# Polynomial Diophantine equation under modulo

Tags: elementary-number-theory

This problem appered in my textbook and i cant solve it, it's in the chapter of the chinese reminder theorom so that's probably related. A solution or hint would be great.[image: Problem 9]

Comment: Use CRT as in the Remark in the dupe. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a242%20combination%20root%20crt) for many concrete worked examples.

Answer (score 0):

$\require{AMScd}$Hint:By CRT we have a commutative diagram
\begin{CD}
\frac{\Bbb Z}{m_1m_2\Bbb Z}@>\sim>>\frac{\Bbb Z}{m_1\Bbb Z}\times\frac{\Bbb Z}{m_2\Bbb Z}\\
@VVV@VVV\\
\frac{\Bbb Z}{m_1m_2\Bbb Z}@>>\sim>\frac{\Bbb Z}{m_1\Bbb Z}\times\frac{\Bbb Z}{m_2\Bbb Z}\\
\end{CD}
which maps:
\begin{CD}
x+m_1m_2\Bbb Z@>>>(x+m_1\Bbb Z,x+m_2\Bbb Z)\\
@VVV@VVV\\
f(x)+m_1m_2\Bbb Z@>>>(f(x)+m_1\Bbb Z,f(x)+m_2\Bbb Z)\\
\end{CD}